# Ansys Mechanical Modal analysis, Parametric materials, mode shape output for each parameter?

Tags: ansys, ansys-workbench, modal-analysis, ansys-apdl

I am trying to match FEA results with an experiment, wherein I need to match mode shapes and frequencies. I am testing different models, and I would like to parameterize several material properties.

It is easy to extract frequencies as a parameter, however since the mode shapes change with the material parameters, this is not terribly helpful. I *thought* that it would be a simple workaround to create an image of each deformation result, labeled with the parameter settings using an ADPL Command as output, however I have now spent two days on this and I am not much further.

My ideal solution would be to extract the images, with the parameter values (eg: "P=.5, Q=.1, Ez = 110MPa") as text within the image.

The farthest that I have gotten is to make an image object under the command in the model tree using the following:

```
SET,LAST
/SHOW,PNG
PLDISP,0
```

However I cannot find this image file and I do not think that it is actually saved.

If there is another (more straightforward) way of obtaining these mode shapes, I am all ears!

Thank you.

Comment: Why not just retain the information from all your design points? Do you lack disk space?

Comment: @Orbit No, retaining the information is not a problem. It is cycling through it for each of the mode shapes. Now that the mode shapes are saved as images, I am able to do so very quickly, and I can use OpenCV in Python to merge images for relatively easy error-checking.

Answer (score 1):

After spending a great deal of time testing, and trying out different things, this is the code that ended up working:

```
!Commands inserted into this file will be executed immediately after the ANSYS /POST1 command.

!   Active UNIT system in Workbench when this object was created:  Metric (m, kg, N, s, V, A)
!   NOTE:  Any data that requires units (such as mass) is assumed to be in the consistent solver unit system.
!                See Solving Units in the help system for more information.


set,list,0   !This lists the attributes for the active set
*Get,nmds,ACTIVE,,SET,NSET   !This gets the number of modes

/DEV,PSFN,NINC   !This disables the incremental naming of image files (I think)

!All of these are string creations
*DIM,P,STRING,80
*DIM,Q,STRING,80
*DIM,Ez,STRING,80
*DIM,mode,STRING,80

! This convers the floats to shorter strings
P_ = CHRVAL(ARG1)
Q_ = CHRVAL(ARG2)
R_ = CHRVAL(ARG3)

!This creates a two-subplot plot for viewing modes from different angles
/WINDOW, 1, LEFT
/WINDOW, 2, RIGH

!This sets up a loop to save the images
*DO,i_,7,nmds,1

!This selects the mode number from the set
set,1,i_,
/Dscale,ALL,0.1  !This sets the scale of the distortion

!This retrieves the frequency of the mode
*get,frq_,ACTIVE,0,SET,FREQ

!This produces the title on each image
/title, P=%P_%, Q=%Q_%, R = %R_%, Mode %i_%, %frq_%Hz


!j_ = i_-6

!This sets the viewpoint for each window (subplot)
/VIEW,1,.25,.25,1
/VIEW,2,1,.25,.25

!This instructs the plotter to create a .jpeg (PNGs did not work! This was one of the main problems that I was getting!)
/show,jpeg
PLDISP,0 !This requests a displacement plot
/show,close  !This closes the plot, so that the next one starts out fresh

!This was the most important bit. Renaming the image file so that each image is not overwritten!
/RENAME,file,jpg,,C:\mode_images\P%P_%_Q%Q_%_R%R_%_mode%j_%,jpg


*ENDDO
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try constructing your title like this:

```
*DIM,P,STRING,80
*DIM,Q,STRING,80
*DIM,Ez,STRING,80
P = CHRVAL(0.5)
Q = CHRVAL(0.1)
Ez = CHRVAL(110)

/title, P=%P%, Q=%Q%, Ez = %Ez%MPa
```

Padtinc did nice blogposts on APDL. Here is [one](https://www.padtinc.com/2011/12/07/manipulating-text-strings-in-ansys-mechanical-apdl/) on strings.

Than you can try saving plots with APDL to your user_files:

```
/post1
set,last
finish
/inquire,aa,directory
ii = strpos(aa(1),'dp')
ij = strpos(aa(ii+1),'')-1
dpn = strsub(aa(1),ii+1,ij)
dpn = strcat(dpn,'_')
/file,dpn
/post1
/view,1,1,1,1
/vup,1,z
/show,png
PLDISP,0
/show,close
/sys,copy *.png ......user_files
finish
/file,file
```

This was also taken from [padinc's blog](https://www.padtinc.com/2013/01/10/saving-mechanical-apdl-plots-in-a-design-study/).

Comment: I am not certain _why_ this did not work, but it did not. 

I think that it failed on two points: First, /show,png fails to produce a file to be copied. Second, the /sys command failed to copy files when a copy was made.